# How to create an embossed button in objective c

Tags: objective-c, button, ui-design

I think it's called embossed button..
Is it possible to make one from code?
I mean like the "Sign Up for Facebook" button in the Facebook iPhone app logging screen.
I know three20 have something like that but i want to create one my self

[image: Two exmaples]

Comment: A screenshot would be useful for this question.

Comment: images are best to use in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create it easily i think because what you will need is only the embossed image.

drag a `UIButton` to your view and the go to attribute Inspector in you IB then under button section change the type to custom.
Now when you have the custom type then assige your embossed image as the background image.

if you are looking for custom code then refer [This](http://www.apptite.be/tutorial_custom_uibuttons.php) link

Comment: I want to know if i can do this programmatically without using any images

Comment: After gaining some experience it seems like you are right :) images are the best for those cases.

Comment: Because I'm not photoshop expert I still searching for this kind of images, so if you know where to find one please tell me.

Comment: Thanks Eyal, I searched for online embossed image creator but didnt found any. you can take a look at these two links hope that work for you. http://vectips.com/tutorials/creating-editable-letterpress-styled-text/

Comment: this link too  http://vector.tutsplus.com/tutorials/effects/quick-tip-create-an-emboss-effect-using-the-appearance-panel/